# React Error (TypeError): Can't add property context, object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use react-clipboard inside a react component to allow a user to easily copy-paste some text into clipboard but my code isn't working. I wonder if I'm missing something obvious. Here is my code (pls ignore the boilerplate for closing the modal):

```
'use strict';
    import React from 'react';
    import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import Clipboard from "react-clipboard";

    class CopyText extends React.Component {
      render() {
        let text = JSON.stringify(this.props.value, null, "  ");

        return (
          <div>
            <p>Press Cmd + C to copy:</p>
            <pre>{text}</pre>
            <Clipboard value={text} />
          </div>
          );    
      }
    }

    class CopyLinkModal extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
      }
      onClick() {
        this.props.onHide();
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <Modal show={this.props.show} message={this.props.message} onHide={this.onClick}>
            <Modal.Body>
              <div className="linkMessage">
                <CopyText value={this.props.message} />
              </div>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <button onClick={this.onClick}>Close</button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        )
      }
    }

    export default CopyLinkModal;
```

For the most part I'm following instruction from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-clipboard but I'm still getting the **TypeError: TypeError: Can't add property context, object is not extensible**
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where do you get this error (line number, stack trace)? When do you get the error (compiling, executing, user action)?

Comment: Bergi - the error originates from ReactCompositeComponent.js:153 - I dont see any of my own files in the call stack. There is also an warning that I think is related: (Warning: Component(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render` in your component or you may have accidentally tried to render an element whose type is a function that isn't a React component.)   The error is triggered when a user clicks a button which itself triggers the modal to be displayed (parent component state is changed to true).

Comment: Hm, did you check that all your imports work as expected?

Comment: Clipboard is the only module I added recently... App works fine without it. There is an outside chance that its buggy or there some issue with ES6 syntax.

Comment: I see you're using ES6 Classes. My guess is that the React version used by react-clipboard precedes this feature. Have a go using React.createClass in your component.

Comment: @gcedo: Or rather update `react-clipboard`. It seems trivial to rewrite in ES6.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up rewriting react-clipboard in ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `react-clipboard` `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.12.2"
}
```

Therefore ES6 classes are not supported.